# Is list.foldRight the same as list.reverse.foldLeft?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the feeling that list.foldRight is the same as list.reverse.foldLeft, but I am not quite sure.

Can someone please either confirm that they give identical results or explain why they are not equal.

PS.: I understand that commutativity is a key difference between foldRight and foldLeft. So for example, when folding over a list of matrices using matrix multiplication as the combinator then the resulting matrix usually will depend on weather we use foldRight or foldLeft.

Comment: Are we to assume that the type of `list` is `scala.collection.immutable.List`?

Comment: Yes Chris, that can be assumed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the definition of `foldRight` for `scala.collection.immutable.List`, `foldRight` is the same as `reverse.foldLeft` if the specified `op` is commutative and the list is not empty; otherwise, no.

```
override def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B =
reverse.foldLeft(z)((right, left) => op(left, right))
```

Comment: Dave, thanks for the answer. So, if we take the matrix example and let z be the identity matrix in that case reverse.foldLeft is the same as foldRight even though the op is not commutative. Because AxB = BoA, where the o denotes the reversed x operation. So reverse.foldLeft is not equal to foldRight only (for all sequences of lists) if the first element z is not the unity/identity element. By unit/identity element I mean an element which commutes with all elements in the universe of elements accepted by List.

Comment: In this case foldRight is `(A x (B x I))))` and foldLeft is `((I x B) x A)`, correct?

Comment: According to http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List foldLeft in this case is ((I x A) x B). So in this case the two would be the same(fold left and fold right). Also, it seems that associativity of the operations matters. If for example, the operation would be to _^2+_^2 then fold right and fold left would give different results, even though the operation is commutative ! Because they would lead to, for example, different polynomials if the list elements were variables.

Comment: So it would be perhaps good to correct your answer if you agree ;)

Comment: Recall that the list is reversed on the call to `foldLeft`. `foldLeft` would be `((I x A) x B)` in the case where the list is not reversed. But, since the list is reversed it is `((I x B) x A), as I say above.

Comment: Regarding your other question. If you run `def f(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a*a + b*b; List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(1)(f); List(1, 2, 3).reverse.foldRight(1)(f)` the results are the same. I think you are forgetting the original question was not, are `foldLeft` and `foldRight` the same ..., but rather is `foldLeft.reverse` the same as `foldRight` ...

Comment: So in the matrix case, foldLeft is ((I x A) x B) according to the scaladoc, then reverse.foldLeft is  ((I x B) x A), if we now reverse the operators too, then it becomes (A x (B x I)), which is foldRight by definition. Yes, indeed commutativity is needed to get from ((I x A) x B) aka reverse.foldLeft to (A x (B x I)) aka foldRight. What confused me for a second that you wrote foldLeft is ((I x B) x A) instead of  reverse.foldLeft :) But yeah, thanks for the answer, I am convinced now that it is correct.

Comment: You are correct I should have said reverse.foldLeft is `((I x B) x A)`. Sorry for the confusion.